# Html5 video tag "autoplay" with play() method

Tags: javascript, html

For some Android devices I have tested the videotag autoplay doesn't work correctly so I'm trying to call the play() method of the video element once it is able to play, I have tried using the "canplay" event but is not being fired.

```
videoElement.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
  this.play();
});
```

Why isn't working? I would like to know a cross browser solution for that.

Comment: Could you please add `console.log('canplay', this);` just above the `this.play();` and check the error console?

Comment: The event is not being fired, so that line wouldn't be reached, is the canplay event new or something? i'm using Chrome 37

Comment: Have Chrome 37 as well - works fine for me... Maybe wrong video source?

Comment: The source os OK but it is a .m3u8 streaming, maybe the event works different with that format